Generating Java classes from XSD with enumeration containing non-ascii values
Using Java 17 and Gradle-plugin com.github.bjornvester.xjc' version '1.8.2
I want to generate java classes from an XSD schema. The java classes is to be used for values read from database. The values in DB can contain the non-ascii characters. Later the java object should be marshaled to a XML string, that validates.
And therefore the XSD contains non-ascii characters in enumerations (several places).
Example:
<xsd:complexTypename="NyType">
   <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:elementname="number"type="xsd:integer"/>
      <xsd:elementname="myEnumType"type="MyEnumType"/>
   </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:simpleTypename="MyEnumType">
   <xsd:restrictionbase="xsd:string">
      <xsd:enumerationvalue="ÄNt"/>
      <xsd:enumerationvalue="Al-sör"/>
      <xsd:enumerationvalue="Sår"/>
   </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>

This does not work. I get errors like:

error: unmappable character (0xF6) for encoding UTF-8

and

error: illegal character: '\ufffd'

The generated Java enum has
@XmlEnumValue("\u00c4Nt")
Ä_NT("\u00c4Nt"),
@XmlEnumValue("AL-s\u00f6r")
AL_SÖR("AL-s\u00f6r"),

I dont know how to solve this in a good way.
If I change all åäöÖÅÄ to aAoO in the XSD it works fine. But then the values from DB will not match then enum.
I have tried in the xjc bindingfile to change the enum by adding (example)
<jaxb:bindings node="//xsd:simpleType[@name='MyEnumType']/xsd:restriction/xsd:enumeration[@value='ÄNt']">
         <jaxb:typesafeEnumMember  name="ANT"/>
</jaxb:bindings>

With this the enum changes to
   @XmlEnumValue("\u00c4Nt")
   ANT("\u00c4Nt");

and the second error disapears,  "unmappable character error" remains...
The error points to a line in the generated javadoc-comment.
How do I replace the value in the enum as well?
Or is it better to get xjc to not generate the enum values at all? Is so how to I configure that in the xjc bindingfile? Doing it like this doesn seem right..
<jaxb:bindings node="//xsd:simpleType[@name='MyEnumType']/xsd:restriction/xsd:enumeration[@value='ÄNt']">
         <jaxb:typesafeEnumMember  name=""/>
   </jaxb:bindings>

If I get the xjc jaxb generation to pass, will it be possible to map to the correct values (as in DB) when generating XML from the java obejcts?

Could you tell what tool you're using for java generation ? I tried your XSD enum in my code and everything is working fine with JDK 17 too (my java generated files are UTF8 encoding)

Im using IntelliJ with gradle plugin com.github.bjornvester.xjc

It seems it's explained in the plugin documentation - choosing the file encoding. You may try using : org.gradle.jvmargs=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

That makes the errors go away. However the emum value is still like "\u00c4Nt", and it is not possible to add real value "ÄNt" to the java

The unicode representation of Ä is 00c4, so \u00c4 == "Ä" (see https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00c4/index.htm). For me, it should work like a charm :)

Ok, I will check if I made some misstake somewhere
